# HTML CSS Banner Alignment

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me out why my "desc" content is not right under my title in the banner? I have posted my CSS and HTML code. I have also posted the photo of how the outcome looks.

[image: img]

```css
#bannerBottom {
  border: 5px #0087dd solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#bannerImg {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#bannerContent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#bannerContent>span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: steelblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#desc {
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerBottom">
  <img id="bannerImg" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
  <p id="bannerContent">
    <span>The Big 3 - HTML, CSS, JavaScript</span>
  </p>
  <p id="desc">While the server can process information in many different languages, the file that they serve to the client are always going to be some combination of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript!<br>Learn more about the Big 3 here!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can float your image left instead of making it an inline-block element. Also there'd be no need to make the paragraph an inline-block either.

```css
#bannerBottom {
  border: 5px #0087dd solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#bannerImg {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#bannerContent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#bannerContent>span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: steelblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#desc {
  font-family: arial;
  margin-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerBottom">
  <img id="bannerImg" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
  <p id="bannerContent">
    <span>The Big 3 - HTML, CSS, JavaScript</span>
  </p>
  <p id="desc">While the server can process information in many different languages, the file that they serve to the client are always going to be some combination of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript!<br>Learn more about the Big 3 here!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, got it now!

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is because you have:

```
#desc {
  margin-left: 190px;
}
```

... which means the box isn't fitting under the title, so it is getting shunted underneath. Either way, float the image left and don't have margin-left.

Comment: Nope, he was doing that to try and make up for the image width, this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Quick reply... I was just making my answer clearer as you typed! The margin-left means the whole block is.... wait now I'm not sure. I think he should tinker with adding float:left to the image, and removing margin-left on the text.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="bannerBottom">

 <div class="container-banner-img">
  <img id="bannerImg" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
 </div>

 <div class="container-banner-content">
<p id="bannerContent">
    <span>The Big 3 - HTML, CSS, JavaScript</span>
  </p>
  <p id="desc">While the server can process information in many different languages, the file that they serve to the client are always going to be some combination of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript!<br>Learn more about the Big 3 here!

  </p> 
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#bannerBottom {
  border: 5px #0087dd solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#bannerImg {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#bannerContent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#bannerContent>span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: steelblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#desc {
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

.container-banner-img {
  float: left; /* <- pay attention on this line */
  width:25%;
  }

  .container-banner-content{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the `flexbox` route you can float the image and keep your heading and description block level.

I took a few liberties with the markup and CSS selectors, changing them from IDs to classes and other improvements to streamline everything.

```css
.entry {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 5px solid #0087dd;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.entry-img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.entry-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: steelblue;
}

.entry-desc {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <img class="entry-img" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
  <h2 class="entry-title">The Big 3 - HTML, CSS, JavaScript</h2>
  <p class="entry-desc">While the server can process information in many different languages, the file that they serve to the client are always going to be some combination of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript!<br>Learn more about the Big 3 here!</p>
</div>
```